# IOS Game Center retrieve latest score (not TOP score)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

In **IOS Game Center** I want to store & retrieve **latest score** of local player (Not the TOP-score).

In my game if user looses a game his score decreases. So I want just the latest score not hist top-score.

In apple documentation I find a way to retrieve the top score of the user but not the latest score.

Is there a way to do that?

If I call this method:

```
[leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
```

I get only the top score..

EDIT:------------SOLUTION-----------

I have figured it out. In itunesconnect you can select between Score Submission Types:

```
1.Best Score or 2.Most Recent Score
```

So select #2. And you are good to go. On `retreivescore` you will get the latest score..

Comment: That must be pretty new, I haven't seen that option before.  It's not even covered in the current docs.  (Deleted out of date answer).

Comment: good find - hadn't noticed either